# is there a way to find out which model instance in collection is changed?

Tags: backbone.js, collections

I am new to BackBone. I know Collection can listen to model attribute changes, but is there a way to find out which model instance is changed? I know it may be a dumb question...but I cant find the answer..Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the arguments that event handlers get in the [Catalog of Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can bind an event on your model of collection for achieving this

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.Extend({

 initialize : function(){
  this.on("change",this.callThisFunction)
},

callThisFunction : function(changedModel){

  }
});
```